# VPN Connection don't have access to remote access to VM's

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

The problem is:
Within the LAN have remote access virtual machines, including the VM's (xx1.11 and xx1.26).

Working through vpn in remote location, have access to the entire LAN, have remote access to all machines in the domain, not only have access to the virtual machine (xx1.11 and xx1.26).

You can see the network scheme on this link:

[image]

Comment: Can the VPN server itself reach the VMs?

Comment: Really VPN server(VM host) not reach to VM's

Comment: How many physical interfaces on the VPNServer/VMhost? Can you post the output of ipconfig /all ? Smells like a firewall issue on the VMhost to me.

Comment: ipconfig /all on this link's:
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3858865/image.png)
[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3858865/image%20%281%29.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather new at Hyper-V but on my server I don't have a default gateway on my virtual NIC. Instead I have the default gateway set on my second NIC. This way I can RDP to the VM host via the secondary NIC while all my VM traffic uses the Virtual NIC. On my individual VMs I set the network as needed, including the default gateway. With this configuration I am able to access the VM from remote locations via VPN.

Hope this helps.